# what does this notation mean $(f,g)\mapsto f+g :M \rightarrow N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I have this Lemma from my Abstract algebra notes, but I don't understand what the notation in part b of it means. Can someone please explain it. 
Also to be noted I have the definition of Hom$_R(M,N)$, so no need to define that here.

a) The composition of morphisms of $R$-modules is an $R$-module morphism: if $f\in\text{Hom}_R (M_1, M_2)$ and $g \in\text{Hom}_R (M_2, M_3)$, then $g \circ f \in \text{Hom}_R (M_1, M_3)$.

b) Hom$_R (M, N)$ is an $R$-module with operations

Hom$_R (M,N) \times \text{Hom}_R (M,N )\to \text{Hom}_R (M,N)$,

$(f,g) \mapsto  f+g :M \rightarrow N$,

$m \mapsto f(m)+g(m)$;

and

$R\times\text{Hom}_R (M, N) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_R (M,N)$,

$(a,f)\mapsto a \cdot f: M \rightarrow N$,

$m \mapsto a \cdot f (m)$:

Answer (score 0):

It means that $(f,g)$ gets mapped to $f+g$ where $f+g$ is considered as an elment of $Hom_R(M,N)$ i.e. $(f+g)$ maps elements of$M$ to elements of $N$ and furthermore $(f+g)(m)$ is defined as $(f+g)(m):=f(m)+g(m)$.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a function from a set to another you have to specify the sets, namely the domain and the codomain, and what the function does to an element of the domain, i.e. which element of the codomain is it mapped to.

\begin{align*}
Hom_R (M,N) \times Hom_R (M,N ) &\to Hom_R (M,N) \\
(f,g) &\mapsto f+g 
\end{align*}

Here the domain is $Hom_R (M,N) \times Hom_R (M,N )$. This is the set of all ordered pairs of $R$-linear homomorphisms from $M$ to $N$.

The codomain is $Hom_R (M,N )$, the set of all $R$-linear homomorphisms from $M$ to $N$.

and what this function does, suggested by the notation $(f,g) \mapsto f+g$, is that it takes a pair of homomorphisms and adds them together. Here $f+g$ is the homomorphism defined by $(f+g)(m) = f(m) + g(m)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:M\rightarrow N$ and $g:M\rightarrow N$ are two $R$-module homomorphisms, then $f+g$ is also a map from $M\rightarrow N$ which maps any $m\in M$ to $f(m)+g(m)\in N$ i.e. $$(f+g)(m)=f(m)+g(m)$$ This map $f+g$ is also an $R$-module homomorphism.

So the map $\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)\times\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)\rightarrow \textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$ takes every element $(f, g)\in\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)\times\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$ to an element $f+g$ defined above which is again an element of $\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$.

Similarly if $a\in R$ and $f\in\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$ then $a\cdot f$ is a map which takes $m\in M$ to $a\cdot f(m)\in N$ i.e. $$(a\cdot f)(m)=a\cdot f(m)$$ Again it can be proved that this map is an $R$-module homomorphism so this maps $R\times \textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)\rightarrow\textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$ ; $(a, f)\mapsto a\cdot f$.